# Fit labels nicely inside Pie Chart Slices

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to make the labels appear inside the pie chart, but with an even distance from the pie border. I'm using `distance: -30` to make the labels stay inside of the pie, but it seems to be applied to the top of the labels' box rather than to a mid point or as margin. This causes the labels to look unevenly placed.

Is there a way to place the labels at an even distance from the border?

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-distance/

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Not really, as it shows the same problem but it's less obvious as the labels are smaller.

Comment: Feel free to take a part in [this discussion](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3880).

Comment: @PawełFus - Thanks. I guess a solution isn't likely to appear very soon then?

Comment: Hard to say, I don't know any ETA for this.